# Postgres 9.6 Index-only scan

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

**Postgres has [new release](https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1703/) 9.6** - I have read the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-index-only-scans.html) about the index-only scan.
I'm aware of postgres tables' heap, and I know how partial indexes(or indexes in general) work.
I just don't understand the benefit of index-only.

#### Questions

- What really changed? Didn't we used index only scan already?
- How and when should I use them to get the best benefits?

*non related background:*
I'm dealing with tables with 6B rows with a lot of `INSERT`s and `SELECT`s in production environments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Quote from the release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release-9-6.html#AEN130517)

> Allow use of an index-only scan on a **partial index** when the index's WHERE clause **references columns that are not indexed**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So in 9.5 and before the following index could not be used for an index only scan:

```
create index on foo (col1, col2)
   where col3 = 42;
```

Because `col3` wasn't part of the indexed columns. This has changed in 9.6